Ubuntu Mechanical Keyboards
My Logitech K845 'brown' keyboard does NOT work with Ubuntu 24.01.1 (or Debian or Kali). I no longer use Windows boxes, but want to stay with a mechanical keyboard (red or brown) that does not cost major money. What can you recommend for a keyboard that works with Ubuntu? Either wired or wireless, but full-sized 101 keys. Logitech has the MX that says it supports Linux, but people have reported problems with it. I'm using it on a Dell XPS with an Intel Core i7 processor.
Is there a recommended mechanical 'brown' switch keyboard for Ubuntu users (wired is fine) that is dependable? I'll take 'red' if that's all there is, but no clicky. Cherry switches would be nice, but any switches that are well-built are acceptable.

Please refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll note "Shopping or Hardware Recommendations" are off-topic on this more narrow focused Q&A support site.

Suggest ask this question on the Hardware Recommendations stack. A search for Mechanical Keyboards finds some existing questions.

Because of the restricted scope of the AskUbuntu website, I think you have better luck getting useful advice about hardware for Ubuntu at https://discourse.ubuntu.com/c/support-and-help/306

Have you updated UEFI firmware and is UEFI settings have USB settings. You need full USB support or specific USB keyboard & mouse support or similar settings that vary a lot by UEFI vendors.

it sounds like your keyboard may only be partially functional - the backlighting is not working. if this is the case, see the comment here: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxhardware/comments/l20xhc/any_word_on_how_linux_friendly_the_logitech_k845/ where the reddit user ArchFFY00 suggests using the linux application "Solaar" to configure your model of keyboard. Solaar can be found here: https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar. Solaar also appears to be available in the Ubuntu Software Manager, making it very easy to install. it may well solve your problems.
